# Finding the second largest element in array without sorting

Tags: c, arrays

I know about the single traversal method initialising two variables to `INT_MIN`. But my question is why do we initialise two variables to `INT_MIN` and also what is the purpose of `INT_MIN` here?

Why can't we initialise two variables to its first element like I have done in the code below? Because when I hand-checked the code manually, I found nothing wrong. So why doesn't the code run properly?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x[10];
    int i, n;
    int first = x[0];
    int second = x[0];

    printf("Input the size of array :");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Input %d elements in the array :\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("x[%d]: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (first < x[i]) {
            second = first;
            first = x[i];
        } else
        if (x[i] > second && x[i] != first) {
            second = x[i];
        }
    }

    if (second == first)
        printf("There is no second largest element\n");
    else
        printf("\nThe Second largest element in the array is: %d", second);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should explicitly explain what happens when the code doesn't run properly.  Post your input, expected output, and the output you actually get.

Comment: Also `n` could be larger than `10`, the size of your array.

Comment: Did you try to debug it? You should find the error very fast.

Comment: You need to read elements of `x` BEFORE assigning `first = x[0]` and `second = x[0]`, not AFTER.    Since elements of `x` are initially uninitialised, the initialisations of `first` and `second` both give undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

- the array `x` is defined with a length of `10`, but uninitialized when you set `first` and `second` to the value of its first element.
- you do not test the return value of `scanf()`, leading to undefined behavior in case of input failure.
- you do not test of `n` is in less or equal to `10` before reading values into `x`.
- you need to special case `n <= 0` as no values will be read into `x`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x[10];
    int i, n, first, second;

    printf("Input the size of array :");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0 || n > 10) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (n <= 0) {
        first = second = 0;
    } else {    
        printf("Input %d elements in the array:\n", n);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("x[%d]: ", i);
            if (scanf("%d", &x[i]) != 1) {
                printf("invalid input\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        first = second = x[0];
        for (i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            if (first < x[i]) {
                second = first;
                first = x[i];
            } else
            if (x[i] > second && x[i] != first) {
                second = x[i];
            }
        }
    }

    if (second == first)
        printf("There is no second largest element\n");
    else
        printf("\nThe Second largest element in the array is: %d\n", second);

    return 0;
}
```

Regarding an alternative implementation where `first` and `second` are initialized to `INT_MIN` and the loop starts at `i = 0`, the trick is `INT_MIN` is the smallest possible `int` value, so `first` will compare `<=` to all values of the array and therefore will not shadow a smaller value. It is also a good default return value for a function that finds the maximum value in an array when passed an empty array.

For your case study, the `INT_MIN` approach is does not work and the algorithm would fail on an array with a single repeated value: at the end of the scan, `first` would be set to that value and `second` would still be `INT_MIN`.

- testing `first == second` would yield a second largest value equal to `INT_MIN`, which is incorrect.
- testing `second == INT_MIN` to determine if all values are identical would be incorrect too as an array with values `{ 1, INT_MIN }` would indeed have a second largest value equal to `INT_MIN`.

Your approach works correctly and the alternative would need to be written differently, with an extra variable. Indeed the solution presented in [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-second-largest-element-array/) is incorrect, and so is [this one](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-second-largest-element-in-an-array-with-optimization), [this one](https://codeforwin.org/2015/11/c-program-to-find-second-largest-number-in-array.html), [this one](http://www.techcrashcourse.com/2016/08/program-to-find-largest-and-second-largest-element-array.html) and countless more random code across the Internet.

Answer (score 4):

I've added some comments where I saw some problems. Hopefully I caught all the problems. Code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // int x[10]; I moved this to under where you ask the user for the array size.
    int i, n;
    // int first=x[0]; This should be written after the user has inputted their numbers. Because what is in x[0]? user hasn't entered anything yet
    // int second=x[0]; Same reason as ^

    printf("Input the size of array :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int x[n]; // This should be here because you asked the user what the size of the array is.

    printf("Input %d elements in the array :\n",n);
       for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
          printf("x[%d]: ", i);
          scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        }
    // You should put your first and second int's here
    int first=x[0]; 
    int second=x[0];

    for (i=0; i<n ; ++i)
     {
        if (first<x[i])
        {
            second = first;
            first = x[i];
        }

        else if (x[i] > second && x[i] != first)
         {
            second = x[i];
         }
    }

    if (second == first)
        printf("There is no second largest element\n");
    else
        printf("\nThe Second largest element in the array is: %d", second);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out and could you explain me the use of INT_MIN for initialising? I'm sorry I'm still new to this.

Comment: You could start the searching `for` loop at `i = 1` since you know that `x[0] == first` and `x[0] == second`.

Comment: @debrisoroids: the reason the code uses `INT_MIN` is that there cannot be an integer value smaller than the minimum integer value.

Answer (score 2):

```
int first=x[0];
int second=x[0];
```

`x` isn't initialized yet.

Answer (score 2):

All solution is better, but some fail when the same items available in the array

- like,

int arr[] = {56, 41, 19, 33, 13, 23, 25, 56};

56 available in two times,

so for this solution,

```
 int arr[] = {56, 41, 19, 33, 13, 23, 25,56};
 var max = arr[0];
 var secMax=-1;
 var size = arr.length;
   
   for(var l = 1; l < size; l++) {
     if (max < arr[l]) {
       secMax = max;
       max = arr[l];
     } else if (secMax < arr[l] && arr[l] != max) {
       secMax = arr[l];
     }
   }
   System.out.println("Second largest number :-" + secMax);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prints -1 if no second largest element is found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int findNotSame(long long int a[],long int n)
{
    long long int temp = a[0];
    int flag = 0;
    long int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=temp)
            return 1;         
    }
    return 0;
}

long long int findMax(long long int a[],long int n)
{
    long  int i;
    long long int max = a[0];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>max)
            max =  a[i];
    }
    return max;
}

int main() {

    long int i,j,n;
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    long long int a[n];
    if(n<2)   //There cannot be scond largest if there;s only one(or less) element.
    {
        printf("-1");
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)  //Read elements.
        scanf("%lld",&a[i]);


    if (!findNotSame(a,n))   //Check if all the elements in array are same if so, then -1.
    {
        printf("-1");
        return 0;
    }

    long long int max = findMax(a,n);  //Find maximum element(first).

    long long int max2 = -999999999999999; //Initialize another max which will be the second maximum.

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)  //Find the second max. element.
    {
        if(a[i]>max2 && a[i] != max)
            max2 =  a[i];
    }
    if(max == max2) //Incase if second max(largest) is same as maximum
        max2 = -1;

    printf("%lld",max2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers were not working when first element is largest, so we have to add 1 more additional check.

```
public class SecondLargestArrayWithoutSorting {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[] = new int[] {10, 2, 6, 4, 5};
        //int arr[] = new int[] {1};
        int position = getSecondLargestPosition(arr);
        if(position == -1) {
            System.out.println("No Second Position");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Second Largest Value is " + arr[position]);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static int getSecondLargestPosition(int arr[]) {
        if(arr.length <= 1) {
            return -1;
        }
        
        int first = 0;
        int second = 0;     
        
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[first] < arr[i] ) {
                second = first;
                first = i;
            } else if (arr[first] != arr[i]) {
                if(arr[second] < arr[i]) {
                    second = i;
                } else if (arr[second] == arr[first]) {
                    second = i;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return second;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import ast
input_str = input()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)
if len(input_list)<2:
    print("not present")
else:
    i=input_list[0]
    j=i
    for index_val in input_list[1:]:
        if i<index_val:
            j=i
            i=index_val
        elif index_val>j and index_val!=i:
            j=index_val
        elif i==j and index_val<j:j=index_val
    if i==j:
        print("not present")
    else:
        print(j)
```

Comment: This code uses 2 pointer technique to avoid sorting  and do solving in o(n) time.

Answer (score -1):

This works,

```
val arr=Array(4,1,2,4,5,5,7,18,10,5,7)

var firstAndSecondIndex:(Int,Int)=null

for(indexVal <- 2 to (arr.size -1))
firstAndSecondIndex match {
case null => 
println("0,0")
firstAndSecondIndex=(0,1)
case value =>
value match {
case value if arr(indexVal) == arr(value._1) || arr(indexVal) == arr(value._2) =>
println("equals")
case value if arr(indexVal) > arr(value._1) =>
println("1,0")
value match {
case value if arr(indexVal) > arr(value._2) && arr(value._1) > arr(value._2) =>
firstAndSecondIndex=(indexVal,value._1)
case value if arr(indexVal) > arr(value._2) && arr(value._1) < arr(value._2) =>
firstAndSecondIndex=(indexVal,value._2)
case value if arr(indexVal) < arr(value._2) =>
firstAndSecondIndex=(indexVal,value._2)
}
case value if arr(indexVal) < arr(value._1) =>
println("1,1")
value match {
case value if arr(indexVal) > arr(value._2) =>
firstAndSecondIndex=(indexVal,value._1)
case value if arr(indexVal) < arr(value._2) =>
println("not greater")
}
}
}

val secondLargest= arr(firstAndSecondIndex._1) <  arr(firstAndSecondIndex._2) match {case true => arr(firstAndSecondIndex._1) case false => arr(firstAndSecondIndex._2)}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int arr[] = {56, 41, 19, 33, 13, 23, 25};
int max = 1;
int secondMax = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int getValue = arr[i];
    if (max == 1) {
        max = getValue;
        secondMax = arr[1];
    } else {
        if (max < getValue) {
            secondMax = max;
            max = getValue;
        } else if (secondMax < getValue) {
            secondMax = getValue;
        } else {
            // Nothing Do
        }
    }
}
System.out.println("" + secondMax);
```

Comment: This code works fine. This best method to avoid using sorting and also pre defined functions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional information like a small description on how this works as well as the resulting output from your code. Please [edit] your answer to make it truly great

Answer (score -1):

Java code to find the largest and second largest number in an array without sorting and using a single loop:

```
package programs;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int largest = -1;
        int secondlargest = -1;
        int numberPos = -1;
        int numberPos1 = -1;
        int[] arr = {22, 33, 9000, 70, 9000, -1, -10, -3, 22, 99, 100, 10000};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > largest) {
                numberPos = i;
                largest = arr[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (secondlargest < arr[i] && secondlargest < largest && arr[i] != largest) {
                secondlargest = arr[i];
                numberPos1 = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Largest number is "+largest+" with position "+numberPos);
        System.out.println("Second largest is "+secondlargest+" with position "+numberPos1);
    }
}
```